# Pandas isin() on column containing numbers separated by delimiters

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run an isin() on a column that contains multiple UID's that I would like to search for. I would like to search for the numbers separated by a delimiter (;).

I have provided an example of the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Data = {'UID': ['13', '234', '130', '1245', '1423', '321'],
        'Name': ['Bill', 'Bob', 'Joe', 'Tim', 'Rick', 'Mike'],
        'Score': ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'],
        'Friends_With': ['80', np.nan, '13;234', '1423;180;908', '130', '2345']}

df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns= ['UID', 'Name', 'Score', 'Friends_With'])
```

The "Friends_With" field contains the UID of each individual. I am able to search through the "Friends_With" of Bill, Rick and Mike because they only have one UID in their "Friends_With" field. However, I would like to look at the friends of Joe and Tim. Where Joe has 2 UID's in his "Friends_With" column and Mike has 3 UID's.

My end goal is, if an individual (Person1) with a "Score" of 0 is friends with another individual (Person2) with a "Score" of 1, I would like Person1's "Score" to be changed to 1 rather than 0.

Here is the code that I have tried, it works well for when there is only one UID in the "Friends_With" column.

```
df["Friendship Score"] = df["Friends_With"].isin(df["UID"])
```

I am currently creating a new Boolean column because if I try something along the lines of the following I get a ValueError of, "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous."

```
if df["Friends_With"].isin(df["UID"]):
   df["Score"] = 1
```

---

EDIT:
What would be the correct way to solve this problem when the dataset is millions of rows?

Comment: Where are you getting this data from? SQL? If it has a many-to-many relationship then it might be easier to fix this in the query, rather than in Pandas

Comment: ```if df["Friends_With"].isin(df["UID"]):``` is not row wise, its series wise, so its saying that its sometimes in the series its true and sometimes in the series its false, so its ambiguous (thats why it asks for you to use .any(), or .all()). You should use ```df['Score']=np.where(df["Friends_With"].isin(df["UID"]), 1, 0)``` instead.

Comment: I am getting the data through a download of a csv file from a website. I don't have too much experience with SQL queries.

Comment: Then it's a dead-end on the SQL side. I was wondering if there was another angle of attack for you, but that's in the hands of the website so don't bother investigating SQL (well, for _this_ problem, not in general :P )

Comment: This problem can be complicated because order matters. For instance if A -> B and B - > C. and only C is 1, then the result is sensitive to the order in which you check A and B. Should it cascade so everyone is 1 in this case? or could you possibly end up with 0, 1, 1 (i.e you check A - > B before you check B -> C and change B to 1). Or are we just doing a single change all at once?

Comment: Ideally, in the end I would like the score column to be [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]. For ex, I would assign Tim a Score of 1 since he is related to Rick (whom has 1). I would also assign Joe a value of 1 since he is related to Bill (whom has 1) & Bob (whom has 0). I would not assign Bob a score of 1 though since no one is in his Friends With category. I am looking for Friends_With is in UID. I do not want to look at if UID is in Friends_With and assign a value of 1 if so. Sorry this may be confusing.

Comment: I understand that for this example. But what if you had another person, say 'Mary' who started with a score of 0, but was friends with Tim. Should she be stay 0, because she is Friends with Tim, who was initially 0. Or should she become a 1, because at some point Tim gets changed to 1, and now Mary is friends with Tim, who is a 1.

Comment: Good question, I definitely see how that could get complicated. In my specific case with the problem I am trying to solve, I would have Mary stay as 0 because Tim was initially 0.

Answer (score 2):

Updated using `dot` with two for loops , notice this is o(nm) check

```
s=np.array([[y in x for y in df.UID ]for x  in df.Friends_With.fillna('No').str.split(';')]).dot(df.Score.astype(int))
df.loc[s==1,'Score']=s[s==1]
df
Out[201]: 
    UID  Name Score  Friends_With
0    13  Bill     1            80
1   234   Bob     0           NaN
2   130   Joe     1        13;234
3  1245   Tim     1  1423;180;908
4  1423  Rick     1           130
5   321  Mike     0          2345
```

Comment: Great, I didn't think of using str.split. In this case, Bob should have a new score of 0 because he has an initial "Score" of 0 and is not Friends With anyone that has a score of 1. Tim should be assigned a new score of 1 because he he is related to Rick whom has a "Score" of 1. Sorry, I didnt explain it too well, but in the end the Scores should be '[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]'

Comment: If I had a similar problem where I would like to see if someone is "Friends With" their own UID. How would I do that? Essentially check if the "UID" in the "Friends_With" field is in the "UID" field of the same row. I would then like to create a new boolean column for if they are friends with themselves or not. I then wouldn't need the array and dot product.

Comment: @BKlassen can you show us the expected output ? if the question is different , please open a new tag

Comment: Its a similar question so I believe it will be marked as a duplicate, but ideally I would like a new column created called "Friends_With_Themselves". In the column it should display true or false. If it is true then the UID in the "Friends_With" column is also the UID from the same row. Ex. In the row where the "Name" is "Tim", if a new UID of "1245" is added into the "Friends_With" column the "Friends_With_Themselves" should display true. However, since no one else has their UID in their corresponding "Friends_With" column they should be false.

Comment: Is there a way to speed up the run time? My actual dataset has millions of rows, so it is not ideal. Is there a different way of doing it without using the dot product?

Comment: @BKlassen you can do with split and also good to mentioned panda is not good for million of row try look at dask